# Prepared statement error with insert

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I tried to use, for the first time, prepared statement in order to avoid sql injection but it seems i have a problem when i try to insert or update my database i use these lines to do what i want:

Insert:

```
 $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO my_array (image1,image2,image3,image4, info, type, lat, lng, date_created, status, created_by, closed_by, date_finished) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") ;

$stmt->bind_param('bbbbssddsssss', $image1, $image2, $image3, $image4, $info, $type, $lat, $long, $date, $opened, $user, $closed_by, $closed_by, $date_finished);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Update:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET fullname =  IF(LENGTH(?) = 0, fullname, ?), email = IF(LENGTH(?) = 0, email, ?), phone_num = IF(LENGTH(?) = 0, phone_num, ?) , address = IF(LENGTH(?) = 0, address, ?)  WHERE username = '$user'") ;

$stmt->bind_param('ssssiiss',$fullname, $fullname, $email, $email, $phone_number , $phone_number, $address, $address);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

in both i get a "false" result.

Comment: Retrieve returned mysql error and start with that.

Comment: I do not have any sql errors

Comment: If it's an error in your query, there has to be one. If not, there is no problem with the query.

Comment: Don't underestimate errors before assuming success. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you try to bind 14 variables to 13 values at your insert. About your update: why don't you use a parameter for the username - and may it be that you pass null values?

Comment: @VMai yes you are right about the first part i will try to solve it and see if that works, the parameter $user is not empty.

Comment: OK about the insert i can now import everything i want UNLESS of the images for some reason it does not seem to work.

Comment: Btw. your queries don't return a resultset. So I would think that `$stmt->get_result();` would not apply to INSERT and UPDATE statements. Use [affected_rows](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) instead.

Comment: @VMai it seems you are right in the update part i get it to work but the get_result is always false how do i know i the above stript works is there an other way?

Comment: As I said: have a look at the value of `$stmt->affected_rows;` instead. Please read the linked documentation. If no row was modified the result will be zero. -1 indicates an error.

Answer (score 0):

In the first you have `$closed_by` duplicate.

In the second you have `$user` in the prepared statement. That must be a parameter.

Comment: I changed that and it know works but not for uploading the images. Any suggestion, as far as the user i look into that right away

Comment: in the insert i get 4 images in longblob type and i insert them to my database the first 4 values (image1, image2...)

Comment: @nicolasmanic And what is not working there? Is there no new entry in the database or are the fields empty?

Comment: i do not get any error but it uploads empty files. If there is no problem with my code it may a problem with the above part i use in order to check if i have an image upload  
`code: $image1 = isset($_POST['image_1']) ? $_POST['image_1'] : "";
$image2 = isset($_POST['image_2']) ? $_POST['image_2'] : "";
$image3 = isset($_POST['image_3']) ? $_POST['image_3'] : "";
$image4 = isset($_POST['image_4']) ? $_POST['image_4'] : "";`

Answer (score 0):

use proper error handling in each of your statements:

```
if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO my_array (image1,image2,image3,image4, info, type, lat, lng, date_created, status, created_by, closed_by, date_finished) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;
}

if(!$stmt->bind_param('bbbbssddsssss', $image1, $image2, $image3, $image4, $info, $type, $lat, $long, $date, $opened, $user, $closed_by, $closed_by, $date_finished))
{
      echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!$stmt->execute())
{
      echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!($result = $stmt->get_result())
{
      echo "Getting result set failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```